# Using insert() on empty std::vector when sorting

Tags: c++, vector

I know ideally to add to a `std::vector` without worry I should use `push_back()`. However my problem set is that I need a clean code to check if the value I am entering is already in the `std::vector` and if not, I have to put in sequential, ascending order. To do that I am doing:

```
vector<Book>::iterator it;
it = std::find(books.begin(), books.end(), b);
if (it != books.end()) {
    *it = b; // if b exists in books, overwrite the iterator
}
else {
    vector<Book>::iterator _it;
    _it = lower_bound(books.begin(), books.end(), b);
    books.insert(_it, b); // here on an empty vector, _it has no values
}
```

The `else` will only run if the value `b` doesnt already exist in the `std::vector`. If this is the first value being checked against it, the `else` runs (since its empty) and the `std::iterator` is at `books[0]`(?).

What makes me cautious about using this is that when debugging, on the `insert()` line, the value of `_it` reads "Error Reading...." for each of the members for which the `std::iterator` is pointing to. Now the program functions and yields anticipated results, but is it erroneously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing works fine. However it is not the most efficient way. Using `std::find` doesn't take advantage of the fact that the data in the vector is *sorted*, it visits every element until if finds the correct one.

Instead of `std::find` you can use `std::lower_bound` from the beginning because that will find your element if it exists and if not, it will find the correct place to insert a new one.

Also it will use a binary search so it will be leaps and bounds faster than `std::find`. Also you don't end up finding the insertion/replacemt point twice.

Something like this should do:

```
void insert_or_replace(std::vector<Book>& books, Book const& b)
{
    std::vector<Book>::iterator it;

    it = std::lower_bound(books.begin(), books.end(), b);

    if(it != books.end() && *it == b)
        *it = b;
    else
        books.insert(it, b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is all well defined behavior.

`lower_bound` will return the end iterator (`books.end()` in your case) for an empty range or if `b` should come after the last element.  `insert` will add the new element *before* the iterator passed to it, so this will be before `end`.  In an empty vector, this will have the effect of adding the element to the vector.

Comment: Which is what I desired; since `lower_bound` returns `books.end()` for the first time an element is being sorted in that `std::vector`, be is being added before `books.end()`, thus to `books.begin()`. Right?

Answer (score 0):

The code is pretty fine. For an empty vector `lower_bound(books.begin(), books.end(), b)` will return `end()` iterator. Passing it to [std::vector::insert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) will work fine.

> `pos` -   iterator before which the content will be inserted. `pos` may be the `end()` iterator

and about your worry:

> What makes me cautious about using this is that when debugging, on the `insert()` line, the value of `_it` reads "Error Reading...." for each of the members for which the `std::iterator` is pointing to.

That's because the `end()` iterator points to the position following the last element, so it's invalid to deference on it (to get a nonexistent element).

Comment: Up 1 for documentation; the post by Galik is cleaner than what I have so that's why I selected it as the answer. Thank you though for the documentation link!